# Datatables - Keeping selected page number after callback

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a datatable which I should change something on it, for example I want to change the status of a content, but this content is in 3rd page on the table. When I change it, datatable refreshes itself to the 1st page. What I'm trying to do is to keep the selected page number and call it back after refresh. Is that possible?

btw, I'm using datatables 1.9.4

EDIT: **SOLUTION**

What I've done is simply keeping the page number in every action that I make in datatable and sending it to the Controller and then using it via TempData. If anyone needs a hand about the solution, just make me know, I can explain more detailed.

Comment: [http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnStandingRedraw](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnStandingRedraw)

Comment: I think I asked wrong question: When I change the status of the content, it goes to server side and when it comes back, it redirects to an action. Does this plug-in work in that case too? I tried but couldn't manage.

Comment: Why is it redirecting to an action? you should just call `fnDraw()` to refresh the datatable

Comment: cuz i'm submitting a form and after submitting, it refreshes the page.

Comment: ok I get it.  I don't know how to fix that unfortunately.  I had a quick google & found [http://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnPageChange](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnPageChange) which may help

Comment: I saw it but couldn't manage to implement it to solve my problem. thanks for help anyways.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I save the datatable state in the local storage to avoid passing the page number all over my app. This is how I do it:

```
$('#offersTable').dataTable({
        "bStateSave": true,
        "fnStateSave": function (oSettings, oData) {
            localStorage.setItem('offersDataTables', JSON.stringify(oData));
        },
        "fnStateLoad": function (oSettings) {
            return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('offersDataTables'));
        }
    });
```

This is very useful when you go to another page and you want to go back (using the back button) to the last selected page.

See also the documentation: https://datatables.net/blog/2012-01-16

Comment: This is the best solution for my problem, thanks a lot.

Comment: You just saved my 4 hours. Thanks!!

Answer (score 26):

Here is how to do it in DataTable v1.10.7:
DataTable Storing the state in a cookie for you.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').dataTable( {
            stateSave: true
        } );
    } );
```

Comment: I don't know why this solution is not upvoted. This is perfectly working for me. I have upvoted your suggestion.

Comment: Because the question is pretty old, like 6 years old, and the accepted answer has been working pretty well ever since. :) But this is answer is the most library-specific and to the point answer.

Answer (score 22):

In DataTables 1.10 you have an ability to stay on the same page after re-drawing if you pass `false` as a first parameter to the `draw()` function.

```
table.row(index).data(data).draw(false)
```

Answer (score 16):

If you are using **server side datatable**, then you can use `ajax.reload()` function to reload the datatable. 
Use like

```
var dt = $("#table").DataTable();
dt.ajax.reload(null, false); // false if you don't want to refresh paging else true.
```

See https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload() link.

Answer (score 6):

If you are update any data using ajax on page number 3 and you don't want that after refresh my data in data table it will go to first page again so here is the solution that will refresh data of table but not redirect you to first page. it will be reflect changes on same page.

> This below **will** **not** **redirect** **to** **first** **page** after refresh/reload data table using ajax

```
$('#YOUR_TABLE_ID').DataTable().ajax.reload(null, false); //without refresh table<<page  will not change>>
```

[image]

> This below **will** **redirect** **to** **first** **page** after refresh/reload data table using ajax

```
  $('#YOUR_TABLE_ID').DataTable().ajax.reload(); //with refresh table <<page will change>>
```

[image]

Comment: It would be nice if you add some explanation along with your code.

Comment: @L.F. I Just add description as well images for better understanding.

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thank you very much! But if you could explain what the 2 parameters to `reload(null, false)` mean, that'd be really great!

Comment: @m.beginner I am glad that this thing is worked for you. and for `reload(null,false)` refer [THIS LINK](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload())

And Using this link if you understand that thing then upvote my comment so it will notify me.

Comment: got the meaning now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Redraw the table maintaining current paging position:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
table.draw( false );
```

Answer (score 1):

fnStandingRedraw is the one you want. http://www.craiglotter.co.za/2012/05/28/how-to-refresh-a-datatable-without-losing-your-current-page-or-ordering/

Comment: The thing is, what I'm refreshing is not only datatable, but also the whole page. This solution works for only refreshing datatable, but when I refresh the whole page, it doesn't work. I found a solution for my problem, I'm updating my question with the solution. Thanks for your help anyways.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I will do it and it will work for me.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/CollectionHistory/Search",
        data: { "licenseeId": licenseeId, "locationId": locationId, "month": monthId, "year": yearId, "pageNumber": 1 },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            if (table != null) {
                table.clear();
                table.destroy();
            }
            localStorage.setItem("manageLicenseeDataStateSave", "0");
            table = $("#collection_history").DataTable({
                "data": response.SalesData,
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "LocationName", "name": "Location Name", "autowidth": true, className: "text-center" }                   
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "bInfo": false,
                "bFilter": false,
                "ordering": true,
                "stateSave": true,
                "language": {
                    "paginate": {
                        "previous": "PREV",
                        "next": "NEXT",
                    }
                }
            });
        },
        error: function () {
            window.location.href = "/Home/HandleError";
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this problem and my solution has been to use the draw method passing the false value as a parameter:

```
this.datatableElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => { 
    dtInstance.draw(false); 
});
```

I'm using `"angular-datatables": "^11.2.0"` version.