# How to prevent pagination reset in datatable using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

TLDR;

How to stay on the page in datatable using ajax my way?

**My problems**

1. User click a button in the table. That particular row will be updated and I will call the `fn_GetData()` function.
2. I will fetch the updated data from database into the table again, thus updating the row (actually entire table was updated).
3. If the row is few page later, when the table reload, it will back to the first page again. How to remain on that particular page?

Btw I tried `.ajax.reload( null, false )` is not working

**Ajax wrapped in javascript function**

```
function fn_GetData(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "action/myfile.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {'GetData':''},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.status=='success'){
                if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable("#myTable")) {
                    $('#myTable').DataTable().clear().destroy();
                }

                var myTable = $('#myTable').html(data.table).DataTable({
                    responsive: {
                        details: {
                            type: 'column'
                        }
                    },
                    "dom": 'Bplirtip',
                }).columns.adjust().responsive.recalc();

                //myTable.ajax.reload( null, false );
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log(xhr);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158375/datatables-keeping-selected-page-number-after-callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable state saving:

```
  $('#example').dataTable( {
      stateSave: true
    } );
```

Comment: yes ,this work on four - pagination, filter, shorting and showentry (number of records).