# Refresh page without losing active pagination in dataTable - JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I want to keep selected the pagination of the data table after submitting the form using ajax.

Currently the code is working fine saving and showing the data into data-table format but whenever I try to save the data table, it keeps going back to the first page but what I'm trying to do is to keep the selected page number active so that the user will easily see the data.

Some Thread that I read these past few hours.

```
stateSave: true
```

Adding this code will resolve the problem. But I tried it nothing happens

My Current Ajax code:

```
    function refresh_Table(){
    $.ajax({
        headers:{'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
        url: "{{ route('printdate') }}",
        method: "GET",
        data:{}, 
        success:function(data)
        {
            $('#table_DTR').html(data);

            $('#table_time_records').dataTable({
                "serverSide": false, 
                "retrieve": true, 
                "ordering": false
            });
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            console.log(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

My Current Saving Data Code in Ajax:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnApplyAlter", function(){

    var a = $('select[name=table_time_records_length]').val();
    validation_altered_data();    
    if(counter_alter_validation == 0)
    {
        $("select[name=table_time_records_length] option[value='365']").remove(); 
        $('select[name=table_time_records_length]').val(a).trigger('change');
        alert("Check the row you want to apply alter");   
    }
    else if(checker_validation == "false")
    { 
        $("select[name=table_time_records_length] option[value='365']").remove(); 
        $('select[name=table_time_records_length]').val(a).trigger('change');
        alert(error);
    }
    else
    {
        var c = confirm("Apply this alteration?");
        if(c == true)
        {
            $('.reason').prop("disabled", false);

            $.ajax({
                headers:{'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                url: "{{ route('applyalteration') }}",
                method: "POST",
                data: $('#alteration_data').serialize(), 
                beforeSend: function()
                {
                    document.getElementById('loader').style.display = "block";
                },
                success:function(data)
                {
                    if(data == "w")
                    {
                        alert("You don't have schedule for this day!");
                        $("select[name=table_time_records_length] option[value='365']").remove(); 
                        $('select[name=table_time_records_length]').val(a).trigger('change');   
                        $('.reason').prop("disabled", true);   
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $("select[name=table_time_records_length] option[value='365']").remove(); 
                        $('select[name=table_time_records_length]').val(a).trigger('change');          
                        alert("Alteration Applied!");
                    } 
                },
                complete:function(){
                    refresh_Table();
                    document.getElementById('loader').style.display = "none";
                }
            }); 
        }
        else{
            $("select[name=table_time_records_length] option[value='365']").remove(); 
            $('select[name=table_time_records_length]').val(a).trigger('change');
        }
    } 
});
```

This image shows the output when I tried to use and play this code

```
    "bStateSave": true,
    "fnStateSave": function (oSettings, oData) {
        localStorage.setItem('offersDataTables', JSON.stringify(oData));
    },
    "fnStateLoad": function (oSettings) {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('offersDataTables'));
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158375/datatables-keeping-selected-page-number-after-callback --- either way, your answer is in there.

Comment: That's the thread that I'm talking about. I tried to play the answers there but it gives me errors.

Comment: @KingRG the answer given in the link **Crayons** has provided uses `localstorage` which you don't appear to have any attempt of using...

Comment: I tried to use localstorage too as stated in the first answer in the related thread

Comment: @KingRG and what problem(s) did you encounter with that attempt?

Comment: In the first answer in the related thread. My data table did not reload the data and when I tried to check the inspect elements to see the errors. There's no error

Comment: I updated the post to see the output of the code that you're referring to me

Comment: What your `refresh_Table();` function is doing?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. refresh_Table function is just simply displaying the data from database. As you can see, onClick btnApplyAlter is my button used to save the data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Datatables - Keeping selected page number after callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158375/datatables-keeping-selected-page-number-after-callback)