# How to redirect to specific page when submit modal bootrap?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatables

I've a modal bootrap view to edit values from datatable, and my problem now is when i edit an user in page 2,3,4.... when i redirect to index it goes to page 1, how can i go to page where i has before editing?

this is what i have in datatable:

```
var table = $('.tablesModel').DataTable({
            "select": true,
            "aaSorting": [],
            "autoWidth": false,
            //"dom": "<'row'<'col-md-2'B><'col-md-4'f><'col-md-6'p>>" + "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>><'row'<'col-sm-12'p<br/>i>>" 
            "dom": "<'row'<'col-md-2'B><'col-md-4'f><'col-md-6'p>r>t<'table-scrollable't><'row'<'col-md-4 col-sm-4'i><'col-md-2'l><'col-md-6 col-sm-6'p>>"
            , lengthChange: true

            , "columnDefs": [{
                "visible": false,
                "targets": hCols
            }]
```

Comment: you need to set "start" properties = your current page for more details click on link https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/32031/pagination-with-server-side-processing

Comment: also, check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158375/datatables-keeping-selected-page-number-after-callback

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using HTML-sourced data, i.e. when data is provided in `<tbody>` element. In this case you can use [`stateSave`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSave) option to enable saving of table state which includes pagination, filtering, sorting and display length.

See [this example](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/state_save.html) for demonstration. Try to change page and then refresh the page.